# Search string for Dictionary Value, then replace matched value with Dictionary's key?

Tags: c#, .net, string, dictionary

So I have a dictionary with Keys that are shortened versions of address abbreviations (which are my values in this dictionary). I need to search a string for if it contains a value in my dictionary, and then replace the value matched within the string, with the key-value from the dictionary. 
For example:

```
Dictionary<string, string> addresses = new Dictionary<string, string>(){{"BLVD","BOULEVARD"}};
var address = "405 DAVIS BOULEVARD";
```

So in the example above, I would want to find 'BOULEVARD' as a match, and then replace it with 'BLVD'. Thus, the new address would be "405 DAVIS BLVD".
The Code below is what I have so far, but I'm not sure how to get the replacement part of it done, with the appropriate key value. Any tips would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
foreach(var value in addresses.Values)
{
     if(address.ToUpper().Contains(value))
     {
         //this is where i get stuck with how to replace with the appropriate key of the dictionary
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you want to replace all strings, if found in the dictionary, with their counterpart. This can be done in a simple loop:

```
Dictionary<string, string> addresses = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
    { { "BLVD", "BOULEVARD" } };

var address = "405 DAVIS BOULEVARD";

// Replace all 'Value' items found with the 'Key' string
foreach(var item in addresses)
{
    address.Replace(item.Value, item.Key);
}
```

If you want to do a case-insensitive replace, [`RegEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_) is also a good way to go:

```
foreach(var item in addresses)
{
    address = Regex.Replace(address, item.Value, item.Key, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution would be to invert your key and value, 
`Dictionary<string, string> addresses = new Dictionary<string, string>(){"BOULEVARD","BLVD"};`
Then you can replace just by looking up the key:
`address = address.Replace(key, addresses[key]);`

Answer (score 0):

We can find the keyvalue pair first, and replace using:

```
Dictionary<string, string> addresses = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "BLVD", "BOULEVARD" } };
var address = "405 DAVIS BOULEVARD";

KeyValuePair<string,string> keyValue =
    addresses.FirstOrDefault((x) => address.ToUpper().Contains(x.Value));

if(keyValue.Value != null)
{
    address = address.ToUpper().Replace(keyValue.Value, keyValue.Key);
}
```

Note: Please add `using System.Linq;` (if it doesn't exist) for the extension method `FirstOrDefault`